# Bluetooth Peripheral Stuck in "Connecting" State On iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, adafruit

I am trying to connect to my Arduino project that is using the BlueFruit BLE spi module. I am having an issue when trying to connect using my iOS app. After I have found the device I try to connect to it but the state gets stuck in 'connecting' state=1. This prevent me from searching the services and such because a 'connected' state isn't achieved
Here is a code snip...

```
//check state of the bluetooth on phone
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOff{
        //TODO: ADD SAVE DATA TO REALM BEFORE DISSMISSING
        errorView.isHidden = false
    }
    if central.state == .poweredOn{
        errorView.isHidden = true
        //scan for peripherals with the service i created
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
}

//devices found(should only be ours because we will create Unique serviceID)
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    // get advertisement data and check to make sure the name is matching. set it as the peripheral then make connection
    if let peripheralName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
        print("NEXT PERIPHERAL NAME: \(peripheralName)")
        print("NEXT PERIPHERAL UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")

    if peripheralName == nameID{
        manager.stopScan()
        self.peripheralHalo = peripheral
        peripheralHalo!.delegate = self
        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)

       while(peripheralHalo?.state.rawValue == 1)
       {
            if(manager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [serviceID]).count > 0 ){
                print("\(manager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [serviceID]))")
            }
        }
    }
        print("Connected!!")
    }
```

When I call manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil) , the peripheral tries to connect. I add the following while loop for testing and always shows the state as "connecting". I have tried the LightBlue iOS app and i can properly connect and receive notifications of characteristic value changes so the Arduino firmware should be all good.PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want that `while` loop; This will just block the Core Bluetooth delegate thread.  After issuing the `connect` you will get a call to the [`didConnect`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518969-centralmanager) `CBCentralManagerDelegate` method.  Once the peripheral is connected you need to call [`discoverServices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518706-discoverservices) on the peripheral, which will give a callback to the `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` peripheral delegate method.  You can then discover the characteristics in a similar way.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
// get advertisement data and check to make sure the name is matching. set it as the peripheral then make connection
    if let peripheralName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
        print("NEXT PERIPHERAL NAME: \(peripheralName)")
        print("NEXT PERIPHERAL UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")

        if peripheralName == nameID {
            self.peripheralHalo = peripheral
            central.stopScan()
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, 
              didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Connected!!")
    peripheralHalo!.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([serviceID)
}
```

Also, if you are going to store something that identifies which peripheral you want to connect to, I suggest you use the identifier and not the name as the name can change.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have tried it without the while loop and neither 'didconnect' nor 'didfailconnect' every get called.

Comment: Thanks Paul that did it! I thought I had tried everything, spent hours on top of hours staring at it.  The only thing I switched from your posted code was my hard reference to the peripheral and setting delegate had to be made in didDiscover. It kept dropping the connection otherwise

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that.  I was just writing some code to test.